# how to access my assets folder videos?

Tags: android, video, directory, assets

I have some videos in assets folder, I wish to view that videos in grid view.

I don't know how to view in grid view. If I click in particular video in grid view then only I want to play.

I am confused please help me / give me some useful link.

Comment: Googling... habit saves you from confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial for showing images in `GridView`. Showing videos should be very similar:

http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html

Comment: It doesn't matter where the file is. You can open an asset file like this: `InputStream input = context.getAssets().open(fileName);`

Comment: ok fine. i have 10videos in assets folder i want show all videos in my grid view.